# xamarin -Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Id. how do i fix this

Tags: c#, xamarin

i keep getting this error message. it my seconded week on the job, really need help. be very thankful any thing i get.

this is cs code

```
public class PhotoViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView Image { get; set; }
    public TextView Caption { get; set; }
    public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView,Action<int> listener) : base (itemView)
    {
        Image =     itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Android.Resource.Id.imageView);
        Caption =     itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.textView);
        itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(base.Position);
    }
}
```

this is axml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="Match_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardElevation =" 4dp"
card_view:cardUseComppatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
>
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="Match_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="8dp"
  >
  <ImageView
       android:layout_width="Match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
         />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="Match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:att/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#333333"
    android:text="Caption"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
>
```

if you have any more question, feel free to message me

Comment: Is this C? Looks like Java to me.

Comment: If you have cs code, I assume it is C#. This is not C and you should not use C tag.

Comment: it is c# . i thought i used c #. my mistake

Comment: What is the full stack trace / output from the console? Also, did you already try to clean and rebuild? Sometimes, this issues is caused by the Resource.Designer class is not being generated